# Error in dropping database?

Tags: mysql

---

I tried the following mysql query to drop the database.Here am getting the following error in dropping with database.How can I solve it?

```
mysql> drop database xample;
ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database (can't rmdir './xample/', errno: 17)
```

Comment: error 17  is mysql doesn't have write permission in the DB directory.

Comment: Check the permission in the DB directory and check if there is another file which is not the DB, 'drop database' can't delete a file which won't belong to mysql and then won't be able to delete the directory

Comment: Yes, I agree with HEDMON. I have had this error when there's a spurious file in the database subdirectory that doesn't belong there.

Comment: yeah I used the chown and tried .Now its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've copied your database from another server and tried to restore it you'll see issues like this. One fix is to change ownership:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
```

Where `/var/lib/mysql` is the place where your MySQL data resides. It may be in a different location, you'll need to check for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps if you are running on Xampp.

```
cd /opt/lampp/var/mysql;
sudo su;
rm -rf db_name;
```

where db_name is the name of db you want to remove.